# How to download all tickers listed in the Tokyo stock exchange?

Tags: equities, programming, data, market-data

I'm trying to download all tickers listed in the Tokyo stock exchange (according to [their website](https://www.jpx.co.jp/english/listing/co/index.html), there should be 3,756 tickers in total).

What I have tried so far:

- I have tried the [Yahoo-ticker-downloader](https://pypi.org/project/Yahoo-ticker-downloader/). But it can only download around 1/3 of all the tickers available.
- I also tried [pytickersymbols](https://pypi.org/project/pytickersymbols/). But the lib doesn't cover the Tokyo stock exchange.
- According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338608/download-all-stock-symbol-list-of-a-market), all major stock exchange should provide a list of all tickers available. But I failed to find such info from their website.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: The "tickers" are actually numbers like 7201 for Nissan Motors. The tokyo stock exchange has a 'listed company search' that will retrieve all of them if you specify no search criteria (it could be a little tedious to download thousands of them in chunks of 100 but it seems doable). In the First Section and Second Section there are 2186 and 475 stocks respectively, these are probably the ones that matter to most foreigners? In any case, do specify the Section(s) you want in the Search criteria..

Comment: @noob2 Thanks for the suggestion. I'm thinking about doing this more programmatically. But I'll definitely follow your suggestion if no easier ways available.

Comment: If you have access to Bloomberg, find the Tokio index and then use the function "FLDS" to search for "constituents". That should take you to all constituents and you should be able to export the list of all constituent tickers to Excel.